# CSS link address

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've typed my CSS link address correctly in my html code but the CSS is not showing in the live preview. I disable the cache in the devtools pane . I also cleared the cache in my browser but it still isn't working. Below is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>EMRID LIMITED</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
</html>

<div class="box">
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>About</p>
    <p>Services</p>
    <p>Contact us 24/7</p>
</div>

box{
    background-color: darkolive-green;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width:7000px ;
}
```

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful, they are hard to read, impossible to copy/paste from, practically invisible to screen readers and search engines, and may be hosted on domains that are blocked on some networks. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable.

Comment: It's hard to tell why CSS we can't see isn't working. You haven't even included that in your picture. (and since there is a 200 OK response shown in your log, the CSS is presumably the problem rather than the URL).

Comment: There's no `<box>` element in your HTML (and the HTML spec doesn't allow one anyway), `darkolive-green` isn't a colour, none of your content will be tall enough to trigger the `max-height` and you're unlikely to have a browser window wide enough to trigger the `max-width`.

Comment: any solution as to how I can solve this? @Quentin

Comment: You've got 4 independent problems. Deal with them one at a time. Figure out what you actually want to do for each one. Then look up the correct syntax for each.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that the entirety of your HTML code is inside the HTML tags and your divs and other structural tags are inside the body:

```css
.box {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width:7000px ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>EMRID LIMITED</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>About</p>
        <p>Services</p>
        <p>Contact us 24/7</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I have prepended a `.` to your `box`, which is basically letting the handler know that it's a class. I have also fixed the typo you had with the color value.

You will need to study how to write HTML and CSS so you will fare more easily with your next task.

HTML tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/index.htm

CSS tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/index.htm

Comment: "You will need to make sure that the entirety of your HTML code is inside the HTML tags and your divs and other structural tags are inside the body:" — While that's best practise, it won't help solve the problem at all.

Comment: @Quentin the CSS is applied in the snippet I have shared here. Of course, I prepended a . before the box. I shall write that into my answer, because that's probably unclear for a beginner.

Comment: That's not the only change you made to the CSS and didn't explain in your answer.

Comment: Re edit: So the problem was a couple of typos? "Caused by typos" is one of the standard close reasons. I'm not sure why you voted to reopen this question.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct, thanks for the constructive criticism. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Quentin because the asker is clueless about how to write HTML and CSS code. The fundamental problem here, i.e., the cause of the problem is not the typos. They are but its symptom. The problem is that the asker does not yet understand how HTML is to be structured and just needs a little guidance.

Comment: The structural issues with the HTML are irrelevant to the problem. It would be better to use a comment to direct the OP to an introductory tutorial instead of explaining typos.

Comment: @Quentin added links to tutorials to the answer.